# How can I examine a Java class, without loading it?

Tags: java

I'd like to load some Java .class files and extract information from them. I don't want to load them for a number of reasons, not least being performance. I'd then like to examine them to see what annotations, field, methods etc that they have.

Can anyone suggest what tool is best for this?

Comment: You want to load something without loading it? If performance is an issue, why are you doing reflection/introspection on classes?

Comment: It's a code generation tool that I expect to use as part of a build. I don't want to load the classes as I might have to consider static initialisers, dependencies etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using a byte code manipulation tool such as [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) or [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/)? Both supports reading and writing class files without having to load them via a class loader.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that ASM or BECL will improve performance compared to class loading.
And if in the another (not said) reason, you have classpath issue, you can load it from an inputstream with a new class loader ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass(java.lang.String, byte[], int, int) )

Answer (score 0):

Spring class path scanner uses ASM, you can see how it works by looking at Spring's source code ( handler)