# How to load methods from a jar without loading class?

Tags: java, reflection, urlclassloader

I am trying to read a Jar file which contains few classes and has methods defined in it. I want to get all the declared methods from all the classes without loading individual classes. is it possible?

Here's how I am loading jar file and method(Using class name as of now).

```
File urlclasspath = new File(newJarPath);
        URL urlarray[] = new URL[1];
        urlarray[0] = urlclasspath.toURI().toURL();
        ClassLoader loader = new ClassLoader(urlarray);
        Class<?> myclass = loader
                .loadClass($classname$);

        Object obj = myclass.newInstance();
        Method add = myclass.getMethod("add", new Class[] { Integer.TYPE,
                Integer.TYPE });
        add.invoke(obj,
                new Object[] { new Integer(var1), new Integer(var2) });

        if (obj == null) {
            System.out
                    .println("FAIL: Could not create an instance of the loaded class");
            }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just curious: What makes you want to do this?

Comment: @Yunkhan it's ot possible

Comment: Need it for my eclipse plug-in..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I examine a Java class, without loading it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508247/how-can-i-examine-a-java-class-without-loading-it)

Answer (score 1):

Class is the container for all the methods with in. so in order to reach to a method you must load the class first.

Comment: Oh.. So basically,not possible? Is thr any other way by which I can achieve this..? May be using something else apart from URLClassLoader to load jar during runtime.. :/

Comment: @Yunkhan yes, basically, it's not possible. create instance of your class and use this instance or use static methods of a class.

Comment: You can do this just keep in mind to load your classes from jar in the  current class loader.